# Image not loading in JLable

Tags: java, netbeans

I am making a splash screen for a project, where it displays an icon and shows a loading bar. Loading bar etc works. Here is the image loading and assigning code:

```
initComponents();
BufferedImage buff = null;
try
{
    buff = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Barcode-icon.png"));
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
lblSplash = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(buff));
this.setVisible(true);
```

This was added to constructor of Splash class, but it shows the broken image icon when run...

Any help is appreciated (emphasis on **help**, I want to learn, *not have code sample answers*)

EDIT: added this to code, never fired:

```
if(new File("/Resources/Barcode-icon.png").exists())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "exists");
}
```

Also changing the file string to something else crashes the program, tried both

"Resources/Barcode-icon.png"
"src/Resources/Barcode-icon.png"
and it leads to null input for `ImageIO.read(...)` method

Answer (score 1):

Resources are not files so the File existing doesn't prove the Resource exists, in fact it is unlikely that the same path would work for both. A resource is normally in the jar file itself although it could also be in the appropriate sub-directory of  a directory on your classpath.

Put the results of getResourceAsStream() in a variable to make sure it is not null.

"/Resources/Barcode-icon.png" doesn't mean you should find that file on your computer it means you should find it if you unzip the jar file that you are distributing your application in.

You need to tell your build system or IDE to put it in your jar file. Ussually that means putting in a special directory but not the same directory as you would pass to getResourcesAsStream().

With a Netbeans Ant project (the default kind for Java) you put the file under src subdirectory but you don't add the src/ to the resource string.

eg
src/dir/lena1.png  is accessed with getResourcesAsStream("dir/lena1.png")

Also note getResourcesAsStream("/dir/lena1.png") will not work.

Comment: This project is going to be distributed as a jar, where the resource still does not work, has been tested

Comment: it seemed to be a problem with `lblSplash = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(buff));`, not with the resource loading. I did say in the question: "Also changing the file string to something else crashes the program, tried both"

Comment: the file string affects what the program tries to load, but since changing it made it crash, it must mean the original file exists and it can access it

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... Its the little things...

Using `JLable.setIcon(buff)` works where buff is resource, not stream